# Android: How to set header's height or width in terms of screen

Tags: android, header, footer

I am trying to make an application. It contains multiple activities which all have same header and footer. I want that these header and footer should look exactly same on every screen in terms of height. So i defined `android:layout_height="20dp"` in each Header and Footer.  But it is not looking same in each activity, when number of entities (button) are more in field, size of header is reduced and when there is nothing in the field size works fine.
So i thought that i should define Height or Width in terms of screen. So can anyone tell me how to define size of entities in terms of screen of device. I know how to get screen size

```
Display displayScreen = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(HomeActivity.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int layoutWidth = displayScreen.getWidth();
        int layoutHeight = displayScreen.getHeight();
```

and this is code of header

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llheader" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center"> <!--header -->
        <TextView android:id="@+id/txt_header" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But don't know how to use that in defining  height  or width from java file. So please tell me the formatting of java code how to define size of anything with respect to screen.

Comment: Hey i want to do the same but for button and their side padding

Comment: @BBExpert what do you mean by putting static height in RelativeLayout? do you mean like i did for linear layout header? and why should i remove  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true". I think i used these statements to make the textview align in center of header

Comment: I don't see why you would need to programmatically toy around. As far as I can tell, you can accomplish what you're after perfectly fine using either a `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout`. Perhaps you can add the full code of one of the activities, and potentially an image of what exactly goes 'wrong'?

Comment: @MH sorry i didn't get you. please can you elaborate whatever you are trying to say

Comment: It basically boils down to the last sentence: can you provide more of the layout(s) you're having problems with, as well as a screenshot of what's currently going on and what you want it to be...

Comment: @MH i want height of header and footer should be remain same in all activities, but after using "dip" it's  not working. So i want to it by setting it in terms of screen height. So if you can tell me how to use screen height to set header's height then that'd be a big help for me

Answer (score 1):

Try it...

```
    Display display =((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    int width = display.getWidth();

    int height=display.getHeight();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width/10, height/10);

    todostextview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Give desired value in layoutparams

Comment: can you explain the logic of using this to set header's height

Comment: @VikasGupta Basically i used this method for having fix ratio of height and width with respect to screen size. I applied the same logic for your view object.This will always give you a textview with a height of width/10 and height of height of height/10 of screen size.Or am i unable to understand ur question

Comment: no you are absolutely getting it right, but tell me how can i use it for setting height width of header

Comment: R u understanding the above answer..or there is some confusion in this.Its better give me ur mail id. I cant write there

Comment: sorry but, i am not getting. u r doing this with relative layout but i want this in header

Comment: Replace <Relativelayout> with the layout where you have put your header

Comment: It may seem stupid to you but seriouslly i am not able to do it. I want to use screen width for each button in my xml activity. but i am not able to find out how to do this

Answer (score 0):

`<RelativeLayout>
<header>
<body> <!-- set layout_above and layout_below to footer's and header's id, respectively -->
<footer> 
</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: i have done that but as soon as i provide any layout(with buttons inside) below header. it doesn't work for constant height. Because layout below of header differs in each activity.  Can you tell me any solution for using screen dimensions as width or height

Comment: the answer below mine is the solution then

Comment: i tried that, but was not able to get that logic how to use this screen height to set header's height. :(